# Trying to remove an item from a list using a variable

Tags: python, list

Made a number guessing game, automatically updates a list of facts based off the random number the program creates. If user guesses incorrectly, the program offers a hint from the list. I want the program to remove this hint from the list after it is used, so there are no duplicates.

I tried to assign X as a random number, for the list, then use the same X variable to pop that fact out of the list. .pop, of course, doesn't like that.

```
while counter <= 4 and guess != num_final:
    guess = input("Guess your " + grammar_list[int(counter)] + "number: ")
    Dif: int = (abs((num_final - int(guess))))
    if (int(num_final) == int(guess)):
        break
    elif int(Dif) >= 10:
        print("Your guess was over 10 numbers away. Here's a hint.")
        time.sleep(1.5)
        x = random.choice
        print(x(facts_list))
        facts_list.pop(x)

    elif int(Dif) <= 10:
        print("Your guess is within 10 digits of the computer's number. Here's a hint.")
        time.sleep(1.5)
        x = random.choice
        print(x(facts_list))
        facts_list.pop(x)
    counter = counter + 1
```

How can I remove the fact from the list after I give the hint?

Answer (score 1):

The function `random.choice` does not return a random number, it returns a random value from the sequence you pass as an argument. You are setting `x = random.choice`, meaning `x` is now the function `random.choice` so passing that to the `pop()` function will throw an error as that is expecting an `int` argument as the index of the item you want to `pop()`.

If you want to remove an item using `pop()` you should change to something like this:

```
x = random.randrange(len(facts_list))
print(facts_list[x])
facts_list.pop(x)
```

`random.randrange(len(facts_list))` will generate a random integer from 0 to `len(facts_list)`

Then it will print the item using the value of `x` as an index, and then pop that index.